# Set grease pencil drawings on one level?

Tags: grease-pencil

I am working on a project where I rely heavily on grease pencil drawings (for sculpting), always looking straight on top with 7 on keypad. I just noticed that my drawings are on different levels on the Z axis.

Is it possible to align them together to a certain level and decide on what level new drawings should be? I don't think a screenshot is necessary.

It's not really bothering my workflow, but it would be nice to know.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99000/grease-pencil-workflow-for-composition-or-storyboarding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grease pencil workflow for composition or storyboarding](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99000/grease-pencil-workflow-for-composition-or-storyboarding)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. Probably answer is, although that's not for closing even then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As of Blender 2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/GPencil) you can reproject strokes to existing surface or just to make them planar.

When drawn over some objects from some projection (top one in your case) they look as expected from that projection:

[image: screenshot-blender-in-blender-GP]

If moving viewport projection problems will become apparent:

[image: screenshot-broken-blender-GP-drawing]

To fix that first hide or delete any other objects except for the one you're going to use as a new level for projection. Also make sure that mesh for the projection (probably plane) is larger when seen from the top view than all the strokes.
Then enter Edit Strokes mode, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all. Open *Toolshelf*, choose Grease Pencil tab. Open *Edit Strokes* rollout and on its bottom find *Reproject Strokes* dropdown. Choose *Surface* there to use surface of the mesh you want instead of planar projection depending on the current viewport camera position. Your drawing will be brought to the surface of the mesh you used as a new level.

[image: screenshot-reprojecting-blender-drawing]

Comment: That is a pretty useful answer; I could change my approach by adding my strokes to a plane. Until now, i just drew in the air. There is no way to set the strokes on one level on the Z-axis without adding them to a plane?

Comment: hm i can try and convert the strokes to geometry and then move them to one level.

Comment: @IrenäusBlaszkiewicz as mentioned in the answer you can draw anywhere and then move them to any level you want (note that only selected strokes will be moved). If using Reproject > Planar option strokes will be moved to one level depending on viewplane position (no geometry needed / involved). If drawing over some geometry *and* choosing to stick strokes to surface then strokes obviously will be moved to the surface they find. To avoid that either don't draw over surface or change stroke placement type

Comment: Okay now I get it, thanks. Didn´t know you could do so much with grease pencil. As you said, I went to Edit Strokes -mode and used Reproject-Planar in the Toolbar. That´s what I wanted!