# What are the Hotkeys to adjust Grease Pencil Brush Radius?

Tags: customization, shortcut, grease-pencil

In Photoshop and many other programs, the bracket keys <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> are used to increase and decrease the brush Radius respectively

Does Blender's Grease Pencil have this functionaltiy?
I can't seem to find anything of the sort in the User Preferences.

If nothing exists, how would I go about creating it?

Comment: The blender manual only mentions tablet/touch pressure as a means to vary the thickness of the brush. You would need to implement your own key combination for this functionality.

Comment: No options for this seem to be visible in User Preferences. Where would be a good place to learn how to implement this functionality?

Comment: I am also curious.   The closest data path is `wm.radial_control` with `tool_settings.gpencil_vertex_paint.brush.size` , but it will popup a ring like 'F'.

Answer (score 1):

As for version 2.8 radius can be changed by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.80, while you are in draw mode for the grease pencil object and have Draw tool as active tool.

You can press <kbd>F</kbd> on keyboard and drag the mouse/tablet pen to increase or decrease the radius of the brush.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.9.3 pressing  <kbd>F</kbd> switches to the *Fill Tool* in *Draw Mode*.
The hotkey for *Brush Size* is  <kbd>S</kbd> and  <kbd>U</kbd> for *Opacity*.

These can be set in *Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Grease Pencil > Stroke Paint mode > Radial Control*.

Comment: I am on 2.93.5. In Draw-mode <F> gives me the size-control, I'd have to go <shift>+<spacebar> 1 to get the fill-tool. I can't recognize what you are saying at all?